# How to load related blog post?

Tags: orchardcms

[image]I use Orchard CMS. I have two DIV in my page. In the first DIV the detail of blog post is located. I want to locate the same categorized post in another DIV.

How can I do this?

Comment: u could use Content picker field in blog post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this module [Related Content](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/UrbanIT.RelatedContent), think it fits your needs.

Comment: I add this module to my Orchard Web site.But when I want to edit this widget it doesn't have the tags and terms field.why?

Comment: Can you send a prtscn?

Comment: It does not look right, should be like this http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Media/Default/_Profiles/bd1da296/e60e300f/orchRelContScSh1.png?v=635961423784489250

Comment: Any error at logs? You have add Taxonomy to BlogPost definition, right?

Comment: I fix the error and fill the tags and terms part.Now I want to add related post to my second div.how can i add this?

Comment: You create a new  layer with condition ContentType("BlogPost") and add the widget in content zone....

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this dynamically for all posts in your system, you can attach new part to `BlogPost` type called `RelatedPostsPart`, then use the following driver:

```cs
protected override DriverResult Display(RelatedPostsPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
    return ContentShape("Parts_Blogs_RelatedPosts", () => {
        // To prevent infinite loop
        if (!displayType.Equals("Detail", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return null;
        }

        var blogPast = part.As<BlogPostPart>();

        if (blogPast == null || blogPast.BlogPart == null) {
            return null;
        }

        var blog = blogPast.BlogPart;

        // You can set the count in blog post settings to be configurable
        var blogPosts = _contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Published, "BlogPost")
            .Join<CommonPartRecord>().Where(cr => cr.Container.Id == blog.Id && cr.Id != part.Id)
            .OrderByDescending(cr => cr.CreatedUtc)
            .Slice(0, 5)
            .Select(ci => ci.As<BlogPostPart>());

        var list = shapeHelper.List();
        list.AddRange(blogPosts.Select(bp => _contentManager.BuildDisplay(bp, "Summary")));

        var blogPostList = shapeHelper.Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List(ContentItems: list);

        return shapeHelper.Parts_Blogs_RelatedPosts(ContentItems: blogPostList, Blog: blog);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am new to orchard cms.can u help me more?how can I attach new part to BlogPost?and where can I use the following driver

Comment: Dear, please refer to this [doc](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/), to learn more about how to deal with content parts in Orchard.